# Flash library image get blur(quality reduce?)

Tags: flash, import, png, blur

I get quite an annoying problem when import image into flash (.png &.jpeg).

My image is a 72 dpi png file with sharpen effect , when i use [**Import to stage**], the image imported **in the library** get blurred( eye-realizable), but **the image on the stage** keep original quality(not blurred).I have try change library item properties ( lossless png..etc),import again but no thing different.

 
How can i make the library item have same quality as the image on the stage?
(when i drag library item to the stage it's still blur , except the image on the stage create by [**import to stage**], also tried with jpeg but nothing different)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the solution for this: when you import your image, choose import to stage(dont import to lib)
the choose **break apart**/then **convert to symbol**,there you go, no more blurry image.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done pretty easily by right clicking/ctrl click(mac) on the image in your Library, into Properties. Then set **'Compression'** to Lossless, making sure that **'Allow smoothing'** is unchecked. It should then appear exactly as the image was rendered.